# inserir dados de um array no banco de dados - java

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

Estou criando um sistema que em determinado momento deve criar um pedido e este pedido possui vários itens que coloquei dentro de um arrayList. Tenho uma tabela de pedido no banco, de que forma vou vou criar meu metodo no DAO para salvar os itens do pedido na tabela pedido, sendo que são do tipo arrayList.

Código do pedido:

```
package br.com.pedidosCongelados.domain;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Pedido {

    private long numPedido;
    private Date dataPedido;
    private ArrayList<CardapioIngrediente> cardapio;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private BigDecimal valor;

    public long getNumPedido() {
        return numPedido;
    }

    public void setNumPedido(long numPedido) {
        this.numPedido = numPedido;
    }

    public Date getDataPedido() {
        return dataPedido;
    }

    public void setDataPedido(Date dataPedido) {
        this.dataPedido = dataPedido;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public ArrayList<CardapioIngrediente> getCardapio() {
        return cardapio;
    }

public void setCardapio(ArrayList<CardapioIngrediente> cardapio) {
    this.cardapio = cardapio;
}

public void calcularValorTotal() {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    for (CardapioIngrediente cardapio : this.getCardapio()) {
        if (cardapio.getIdCardapio() != 0 ) {
            total = total.add(cardapio.getValor());
        }
    }

    this.setValor(total);
}
```

Codigo do PedidoDAO:

```
package br.com.pedidosCongelados.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import br.com.pedidosCongelados.domain.CardapioIngrediente;
import br.com.pedidosCongelados.domain.Pedido;
import br.com.pedidosCongelados.factory.ConexaoFactory;

public class PedidoDAO {

    public void salvar(Pedido p) throws SQLException{
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO pedido");
        sql.append("(dataPedido, cardapio_idcardapio, cliente_idcliente, valor)");
        sql.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        comando.setDate(1, (Date) p.getDataPedido());
        comando.setLong(2, p.getCardapio().getIdCardapio());//essa linha não consegui desenvolver.
        comando.setLong(3, p.getCliente().getIdcliente()); 
        comando.setBigDecimal(4, p.getValor());

        comando.executeUpdate();        
    }
```

Comment: Josiane, no seu banco de dados você usa uma tabela para pedidos e outra para cardápios? Se sim, você pode primeiro inserir o pedido, gerar um ID para ele e usar um 'for' para inserir o cardapio em outra tabela com o ID do pedido correspondente. Caso não seja esse o caso, poste como é a estrutura das suas tabelas.

Comment: No meu banco tenho apenas a tabela pedido e produto, não havia feito a normalização de dados criando mais uma tabela Ex.: Pedido_produto. Vou realizar a alteração do projeto criando esta outra tabela e os métodos. Depois posto aqui se deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Voce tem a relação 1:N, então crie a tabela cardápio com todos os itens possiveis. Para cada item você insere um registro na tabela pedido informando o ID do pedido e o ID do item. Se o Pedido 001 tiver os itens "prato1" e "prato2" você então ira inserir 2 registros na tabela pedidos.

Pedido 001 - ITEM 0001
Pedido 001 - ITEM 0003

Quando for ler essa tabela poderá filtrar por pedido. select * from pedidos where pedido.id = 001; e ele trata todos os pratos/itens que aquele pedido teve.